# jquery load external files with http in url parameter

Tags: jquery, load

i've tried jquery .load() function. It is ok when i load files from my server, but i don't know how to load another file from www.

This is my code:

```
jQuery("#blog").load("/index.html");
jQuery("#blog").load("http://crocoweb.sk/");
```

The first one is working, the second not.
On documentations I can't find how to use http as url parameter here. Please help!

Comment: You cannot do that, thanks to security measures in web browsers. Google for "same origin policy."

Answer (score 6):

AJAX is subjected to the [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) as a security feature of the browser. So unfortunately the second option will not work by design.

Another option is to do the include on the server.

Answer (score 3):

You can't load a page coming from another source (domain) via ajax, unless using methods like JSONP. You can check out the ajax jQuery documentation for more information on JSONP.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a proxy between your application and the third party domain. This cross domain querying solution works because you're actually loading the content from your own domain.